# $\gcd(m,n)$ divides $\binom{m}{n} ?$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, divisibility

One of my students asked me this question.

Can anyone please explain the necessary and sufficient conditions such that

$\gcd(m,n)$ divides $\binom{m}{n} ?$

Is it true that $\gcd(m,n) | \binom{m}{n} \iff \gcd(m,n)=1$ or $m =kn$ ?

I'm sure of it in backward direction. I need help about the forward case?

Comment: I think the backwards case is not true. For example, take $m=6$, $n=2$.

Comment: @BenS. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For primes $p$, [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer's_theorem) tells you the $p$-adic order of $m \choose n$.  What you want is that this is at least the $p$-adic order of $g = \gcd(m,n)$ for each prime dividing $g$.  In particular, note that the $p$-adic order of ${m \choose n}$ is the same as that of ${mp \choose np}$.

EDIT: Thus one way to find examples where $1 < \gcd(m,n) \mid {m \choose n}$ is to start with $m_0, n_0$ coprime, find a prime power $p^k$ dividing ${m_0 \choose n_0}$, and take $m = p^k m_0$, $n = p^k n_0$.

Comment: @MuhammadRaselParvej The upshot is that you will probably not find a more succinct characterization than this.  Fix a particular prime power $p^r$ which divides $g$.  Then you know that the last $r$ digits (base $p$) of both $m$ and $n$ are $0$, but these digits contribute nothing to the $p$-adic valuation of $m \choose n$.  The condition on $r$ will be entirely sensitive to the other non-zero digits of $m$ and $n$: it is in some sense completely orthogonal to the gcd condition.

Answer (score -1):

$\gcd(m,n) | \binom{m}{n} \iff gcd(m,n)=1$ or if $gcd(m,n)\neq1$ then the prime factorization of $n$ and $m$ must complain with the following:

$n = p^{\alpha_{1}}q^{\alpha_{2}}\dots w^{\alpha_{n}}$

$m=p^{\alpha_{1}+i}q^{\alpha_{2}+j}\dots w^{\alpha_{n}+k}x$ with  $i,j,k,x\geq 1$

Let's explain it:

$\binom{m}{n} = \frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!} = \frac{m(m-1)\dots(m-n+1)(m-n)!}{n!(m-n)!} = \frac{m(m-1)\dots(m-n+1)!}{n!}$

If $gcd(m,n) = n$ and $m=p^{\alpha_{1}+i}q^{\alpha_{2}+j}\dots w^{\alpha_{n}+k}x$ then

$\frac{p^{\alpha_{1}+i-1}q^{\alpha_{2}+j-1}\dots w^{\alpha_{n}+k-1}x(m-1)\dots(m-n+1)!}{(n-1)!}$

then you want to divide this binomial by $gcd(m,n)=n$ so:

$\frac{p^{\alpha_{1}+i-1}q^{\alpha_{2}+j-1}\dots w^{\alpha_{n}+k-1}x(m-1)\dots(m-n+1)!}{p^{\alpha_{1}}q^{\alpha_{2}}\dots w^{\alpha_{n}}(n-1)!} \Rightarrow \frac{p^{\alpha_{1}+i-2}q^{\alpha_{2}+j-2}\dots w^{\alpha_{n}+k-2}x(m-1)\dots(m-n+1)!}{(n-1)!}$

so it's satisfied when $i,j,k \geq 1$

Comment: You've explained that $m = n^k \implies \gcd(m,n) | \binom{m}{n}  $.

But that $ \gcd(m,n) | \binom{m}{n} \implies m=n^k $ isn't clear to me.

Comment: The "if and only if" is definitely not true. $\gcd(3,2)|\binom{3}{2}$.

Comment: @kub0x That definitely isn't true. Take $m=3$, $n=2$, for counterexample.

Comment: @BenS.  Thanks. But this is a case where  $gcd=1$.  Setting it as an special case, we still can pay attention to the possibility-

 $\gcd(m,n) | \binom{m}{n} \implies gcd(m,n)=1$ or $m=n^k$

Comment: @BenS. Thanks for pointing it out! You are right, when $gcd(m,n)=1$ (m and n are coprime) then $gcd(m,n)|\binom{m}{n}$. Gonna edit my answer now. I think my proof only covers when m and n are not coprime.

Comment: @kub0x Actually, the other direction is not true: take $m=45$, $n=3$.

Comment: @kub0x

Thanks for the fact $m = n^k \implies \gcd(m,n) | \binom{m}{n}$.

I've found an stronger one: $m = kn \implies \gcd(m,n) | \binom{m}{n}$

Comment: @BenS. Thanks for your support, really. Now I've noticed how I can extend my proof to your example. Do you mean that $m$ can be $m= n^{k}p$?

Comment: @MuhammadRaselParvej: You are welcome. I will try putting all together with Ben S. advices and see if it is a general proof.

Comment: @kub0x Not quite. For example, if $m=225$, $n=3$ it still doesn't work. Or even for $m=450$, $n=3$. (I'm just using $3$ because it is small.)

Comment: @BenS. yeah $m=225,n=3$ will yield 0 in division by its gcd. Then are you trying to say that $m$ can be $m = n^{k}p^{i}$?

Comment: @kub0x That's why I included the example $m=450$, $n=3$, to say no to that case as well. I think it is just not a very nice thing. Try graphing it using sage.

Comment: I've edited the question statement. I think it'll help me if you kindly have a look at it.

Comment: @BenS. So do you mean that the p-adic order of the factors of $n$ must be greater in m? p-adic order of $n=3$ is $1$, and in your examples p-adic order of $3$ in $m$ is $2$.

Comment: @kub0x I'm not sure what you mean by that. The p-adic order of $3$ is zero if $p\neq 3$ and is $1$ if $p=3$.

Comment: @BenS. What I mean is that the prime factorization of $n$ must appear in $m$ but with greater exponents in $m$. So if $n = p^{\alpha_{1}}q^{\alpha_{2}}\dots w^{\alpha_{n}}$ then $m=p^{\alpha_{1}+i}q^{\alpha_{2}+j}\dots w^{\alpha_{n}+k}x$ with  $i,j,k,x\geq 1$. Note that $x$ is other positive integer that doesn't appear in the prime factorization of $n$ but still satisfies the division of the binomial by the gcd.

Comment: @BenS. I've given another proof which I think is correct. Would be nice to hear your opinion about it. Thanks for leading me to the correct way.

Comment: @kub0x No problem. I think something is still wrong here: for example, $\gcd(6,2)=2\neq 1$, but $\gcd(6,2)$ does not divide $\binom{6}{2}=15$.

Comment: @BenS. Yes, that's because $m=6=2^{1+i}3$ and $n=2=2^{1}$ with $i=0,x=3$. In my answer you'll notice that $i\geq1$ if you apply that then $m=12=2^{1+1}3,m=24=2^{1+2}3 \dots$ which the resulting binomial is always divisible by the gcd.